# problems in package stringr in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have 2 laptops. Laptop A (win 10 English) works perfect with my script in Rstudio.
But laptop B (win 10 Russian) does not work with the same script in the same version Rstudio.
Functions do not work: `str_which(), str_remove_all(), str_replace()`.
It does not show errors.

I already installed package stringr and tidyverse.
example

```
df1$Htype
Тип дома: панельный

df1$Htype <- str_remove_all(df1$Htype,"Тип дома: ")
```

Comment: Can you print some data with `dput`?

Comment: Don't have the experience of it but it would have something to do with character encoding (default character encoding in Rstudio Windows is system specific). Check this document up: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding. And it is possible that you need to set the encoding in Rprofile...